# Is it possible to cause a continued GLUT MouseFunc entry even when mouse button isn't released?

Tags: glut

im not sure if the topic says it but what i'm trying to do is to able multiple MouseFunc entries even when mouse left button isn't released.
at the current state, the entire program is stuck until the left button is released.

Comment: OpenGL doesn't deal with user input. OpenGL only draws things.

Comment: Nicol Bolas: there is nothing to post since i dont know what code should be written, all i know that the MouseFunc exits only when one of the buttons is released.

Answer (score 1):

See the manual of `glutPassiveMotionFunc` http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node51.html

---

Sample code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

int mouse_x;
int mouse_y;

void draw_square(float s)
{
    s /= 2.;
    GLfloat v[] = {
        -s, -s,
         s, -s,
         s,  s,
        -s,  s
    };

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, v);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

void display(void)
{
    int width, height;
    width  = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    glClearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    /* mouse_y is from window top */
    glTranslatef(mouse_x, height - mouse_y, 0);
    glColor4f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    draw_square(16);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void mouse_motion(int x, int y)
{
    mouse_x = x;
    mouse_y = y;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutCreateWindow("Mouse Motion");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMotionFunc(mouse_motion);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouse_motion);

    mouse_x = mouse_y = 0;

    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: GlutPassiveMotionFunc doesn't deal with 'OnMouseClick' events, only with x,y changings

Comment: @igalk: Then have a look at glutMotionFunc, described in the very same manual page. Use the event handler functions to update variables and register an idle function that processes the values of those variables into the state for drawing the next frame, then call glutPostRedisplay.

Comment: i'm not quite sure im following you, can you elaborate more?

Comment: @igalk: See my code example, which draws a red square following the mouse pointer regardless if you press a button or not. Exercise left for the reader: Change the square color to green if a button is pressed.

Comment: thanks datenwolf, is it possible for me to know which mouse button was pressed? left or right?

Comment: @igalk: add another state variable `button_state` and modify it using a `glutMouseFunc` callback handler. This is what I meant with exercise by the reader. Try to figure it out yourself, this is far more rewarding, than me modifying the code for you.